# Why is flexbox creating unused space below my content?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have some slides where I'm trying to equally space content using `display: flex` but it's adding a large empty area below my content and above the navigation.

When the screen shrinks to the mobile size the empty area becomes much more apparent.

I have no idea why it's doing this, or why switching `display: flex` to `display:table` messes things up even more.

After spending two days I've come for some guidance.

Here's a [test link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/ip-devs/AllState/keep-your-sanity/index.html) to what I have. Click on 1 - 4 to get to a screen using `flex`.

```
<div class="slide" id="slide-one" data-slide="1">
  <p class="deck">You don’t have to wait until bad weather is imminent to prepare for a power outage. Take some time to get organized with these tips.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="section" id="emergency-kit">
      <div class="rollover center">
        <div class="button-container">
          <div class="button"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="text">Create an Emergency Kit</div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <img src="img/emergency-kit.png" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section" id="food-prep">
      <div class="rollover center">
        <div class="button-container">
          <div class="button"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="text">Prep Your Food</div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <img src="img/fridge.png" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

.row {
  display: flex;
  width:100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#emergency-kit {
  width:40%;
  display: inline-block;

  .container {
    max-width: 263px;
  }
}

#food-prep {
  width:40%;
  display: inline-block;

  .container {
    max-width: 167px;
  }
}
```

Also, using [flexslider](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/wiki/FlexSlider-Properties) for the slideshow animations.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

The source of the gap has nothing to do with flexbox. Your flex container (`.row`) is nested within a larger container.

### `div.row`

[image]

### *... is a descendant of* `div.flex-viewport`

... which takes up all the height to the bottom navbar.

[image]

On the smaller screen, `div.row` isn't even a flex container anymore. It's switched to a block element:

[image]

***Possible options for closing the gap:***

- Reduce the height of one of the containers
- Define heights for all container elements between `.flex-viewport` and `.row`
- Apply `display: flex` to all containers, so children can expand the full height of their parent